# absolutely position react-native ImageBackground without destroying all other content styles

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I think this might be a lost caust but maybe someone can help me. No matter how I change my `ImageBackground` style all other nested content is ruined. I've tried the following (screenshots attached)

## Attempt 1

### Ruins all internal styling, does not fill entire page

```
    
    <View style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100%' }}>
      <ImageBackground style={{}} source={{ uri: asset.uri }}>
        {children}
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
```

[image: attempt 1]

## Attempt 2

### Background is closer to filling whole page but not quite there, internal styling is ruined

```
<View style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
  <ImageBackground style={{ flex: 1 }} source={{ uri: asset.uri }}>
    {children}
  </ImageBackground>
</View>
```

[image: attempt2]

## Attempt 3

### fills up more of the page, still not all of it, but internal styling is still ruined

```
    
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
      <ImageBackground style={{ flex: 1 }} source={{ uri: asset.uri }}>
        {children}
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
```

[image: attempt3]

## Attempt 4

### does not fill anywhere close to entire screen, internal styling is ruined

```
    
    <View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
      }}
    >
      <ImageBackground source={{ uri: asset.uri }}>{children}</ImageBackground>
    </View>
```

[image]

## For reference

### as soon as i remove the outer `ImageBackground` component, this is what my page looks like

[image]

I don't think what i'm asking for should be this hard. It's a background image I can display on any screen and has no effect on the components rendered underneath it. This is one of the simplest things to do in css, ios native, android native, etc. without ruining the entire view tree but I've viewed 10 different react native versions of this question without a single helpful answer.

package.json because I know you will ask

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "^2.2.5",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.0.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@rneui/base": "4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@rneui/themed": "4.0.0-rc.8",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.7",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~6.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "^14.4.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "^2.4.6",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image": "^1.3.2",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "^1.5.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "~1.5.10",
    "expo-router": "2.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "metro": "^0.76.7",
    "onesignal-expo-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-track-player": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.10",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.197",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.20",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.18.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.62.0",
    "confusing-browser-globals": "^1.0.11",
    "eas": "^0.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-node": "^0.3.9",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-no-date-parsing": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-no-relative-import-paths": "^1.5.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~49.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-refresh": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-refresh": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "semver@>=7.0.0 <7.5.2": ">=7.5.2"
    }
  }
}
```